# What is the likelihood of being able to see the Artemis exhaust plume from St. Augustine Beach, Florida?

Tags: rockets

[Artemis 1 moon mission set for launch: What you need to know](https://abcnews.go.com/US/artemis-moon-mission-set-launch/story?id=88900734)

A two-hour launch window begins on Monday at 8:33 a.m. ET, meaning the launch could take place anytime over the ensuing two-hour period.

I have been able to see the Space Shuttle's plume from St. Augustine.

What is the likelihood of being able to see the Artemis exhaust plume from St. Augustine Beach,  Florida?

Comment: Rocket engines do the burn of the propellants within the combustion chamber, there is no afterburner. Only jet engines use afterburners.

Answer (score 8):

The Space Launch System [SLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Launch_System) uses the [rocket engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-25) and the [solid fuel boosters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Solid_Rocket_Booster) of the [Shuttle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle). The solid fuel boosters are known for their very intensive bright plume.

So if you saw the Shuttle plume from St. Augustine Beach, you will see the [Artemis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artemis_program) plume too if there are no clouds between you and the rocket.

Comment: Caveat: The last decade or so of shuttle flights launched on a predominantly northerly trajectory that kept the vehicle much closer to the shore as it traveled.  Launching due east won't have the same visibility for folks in that area that the last shuttle launches did.

Answer (score 2):

I live in Merritt Island, Home of the Kennedy Space Center, and have watched hundreds of launches over the past 34 years -- from all over Florida and the Bahamas (many while airborne). You will certainly be able to see the smoke plume from the SLS rocket from St. Augustine! Interestingly, the Solid Rocket Boosters that are used on the Space Launch System are actually (mostly) the same re-used hardware that was used to launch the Space Shuttles during the 30 years of that program -- except that they have added a 5th segment to make them more powerful, and they no longer have parachutes installed in the nosecone, plus a few other changes. They will leave the same dramatic smoke plume that the Space Shuttle did, but after separation, will splash down and sink to the bottom of the Atlantic, never to be used again. Clouds could block your view, of course, but the SLS will fly an easterly trajectory off of LC-39B, and will be a glorious sight, day or night -- once it finally flies!

Answer (score 2):

NASA released this graph

[image]

Appears that you should be able to see it between 20 and 30 seconds after liftoff, weather permitting.

The current window is at night. I was lucky enough to see a Shuttle night launch (STS-76), if it's like that, it should be impressive.

Comment: Nice graphic!  Thanks